# Access of friend to protected function in base class - mixed results with different compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

Consider the code below (SSCCE from long-standing code-base)  - It fails to compile with `clang` (`Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`):

```
/Users/molleson/TestProject/test/test/main.cpp:17:15: error: 'foo' is a protected member of 'Base'
        Base::foo(t);
    ~~~~~~^~~
/Users/molleson/TestProject/test/test/main.cpp:36:6: note: in instantiation of member function 'Helper<X>::operator()' requested here
    h();
 ^
/Users/molleson/TestProject/test/test/main.cpp:6:36: note: declared protected here
    template <class T> static void foo(T&) {};
```

However, it has been compiling quite happily for years with a variety of compilers on a number of platforms including `gcc (g++ (GCC) 4.9.2)` and SunStudio `(SS12_3-20131030)`

Whilst building the SSCCE I discovered that if I change `Helper::operator()()` to regular member function (e.g. `bar()`) it failed on all compilers with a similar warning to that shown above.  Switching C++ standard seemed to make no difference.

I am unclear whether this is a well-formed program or not - specifically whether the `operator()()` should be accessible from a friend of a derived class,  and whether any compilers are non-conforming.

```
class Base
{
protected:    // <<-- compiles if public

    template <class T> static void foo(T&) {};
};

template <class T>
class Helper
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        T t;
        Base::foo(t);
    }
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base
{
template <class A>
    friend class Helper;
};

struct X
{
};

int main()
{
    Derived<X> d;
    Helper<X> h;
    h();
}
```

Comment: First of all the `Derived` class isn't really playing a part here. Secondly, I suspect it's a problem with Clang, because the code looks perfectly fine (except the extra semicolon after the `Base::foo` function definition).

Comment: this code compiles on apple clang `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`

Comment: @RichardHodges: I inadvertently posted the compiling version (by making `Base::foo` public) - fixed now.  Wonder whether you tried that version?   I just tried copying the code here into file and compiling with the same results.  Your `clang` version is the same as mine.

Comment: After your edit then *of course* the `Helper` class can't access non-public functions in the unrelated `Base` class. That's one of the points of `protected` and `private` access specifiers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The role of `class Derived` here is to grant friendship to `class Helper`  - so it's not entirely superfluous. By my reasoning, `foo()` is accessible as a protected (inherited) member of `Derived`, and therefore `Helper` - as a friend of `Derived` would have access to it.  However, what's happening here is that `foo()` is called with the scope operator on the base-class.

Comment: But the problem is that you say that `Helper` is a friend of `Derived`, not of `Base`. That friend declaration doesn't automatically make `Helper` a friend of `Base` as well. Only indirectly through the `Derived` class.

Comment: It does indeed compile if I call `Derived<T>::foo()`.    This suggests that I've just found a bug in no fewer than three 'production grade' compilers from three different vendors, and that `clang` was right all-along  - unless of course there was a standard change with C++11.